# IPtables rules in python using bash script

Tags: iptables, bash, unix

Here is my python script in bash, I am using subprocess.run to call `iptables` command , but I am getting an error

```
subprocess.run(["/usr/sbin/iptables", "-A", "INPUT", "-p", "udp", "-m", 
               "udp", "--dport", "5060", "-m" "string","--string" , 
               "/home/as/Documents/mydf.csv", "-algo", "bm", "--to", 
               "655535", "-j" ,"REJECT"])
```

`/home/as/Documents/mydf.csv` look like this:

- column name `user_name`
- User Name: abc
- User Name: XYZ...
- and so on

I need to use this CSV file to read in `iptables` and reject all the user_name given in column. Error I am getting while running the script:

`iptables v 1.8.4v(legacy): string : bad value for option "-to" or out of range (0-65535)`

Comment: 655_535 > 65_535

Comment: @MarkWagner should I add ```655_535 > 65_535``` instead of  ```655535``` ?

Comment: The error message says that 655535 is out of range, since the highest possible value is 65535. This is what MarkWagner wanted to convey.

Comment: However, the `string` module matches a string to a packet. It doesn't look into files, as far as I know. Therefore, I strongly doubt that your `iptables` command will work as intended, even after correcting the error. Currently, it checks if a UDP packet to port 5060 contains the string `/home/as/Documents/mydf.csv`.